# Typescript - passing multiple component attributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I create a tsx react component like so:

```
export interface FABProps { onClick: Function; children?: any; otherProps?: any }
export interface FABState { onZoomButtonClick?: Function; }

export default class FAB extends React.Component<FABProps, FABState> {
    static getInitialState() {
        return {onZoomButtonClick: undefined};
    }

    render() {
        let {onClick, children, ...otherProps} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="right" style={{"padding" : "24px"}}>
                <a className="btn-floating btn-large blue-grey darken-4"
                   onClick={onClick} {...otherProps}>
                    {children}
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and using it like so:

```
  <FAB id="layout-zoom-button" onClick={this.onZoomButtonClick}></FAB>;
```

Then i get this error in webpack:

```
(27,18): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<FAB> & FABProps & { children?: ReactElement<any> |
```

How do i support passing multiple component attributes like the id property in typescript component?
I am using typescript 2 with ts-loader in webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding the `id` property to the `FABProps` interface:

```
export interface FABProps {
    id: string;
    onClick: Function; 
    children?: any; 
    otherProps?: any
}
```